# How to prevent parent modal closing based on child component validity?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I have a Parent component which has a child Modal component which takes a child component as parameter.
This child modal component has some logic. If the child modal is closing, I would like to be able to check if the child component is valid or not, and cancel or not the modal closing.

```
const ParentComponent: FC<IProps> => {
   const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);

   return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>open modal</button>
       {showModal && 
        <ModalComp 
          close={() => setShowModal(false)}
          comp={<Child />} />}
     </div> 
   );
}
```

```
interface IProps {
   close(): void;
    comp: React.ReactNode;
}


const ModalComp: FC<IProps> => {
   
   return (
     <div class="overlay" onclick={props.close}>
       <p>header</p>
       {props.comp}
     </div> 
   );
}
```

```
const Child: FC<IProps> => {
   const [isValid, setIsValid] = React.useState(false);

   return (
     <div class="child">
       some stuff
     </div> 
   );
}
```

How can I achieve that?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to lift that state up above the modal, so you'll need to do something like create a child valid state in the parent and then pass a callback using the set state function that the child will manipulate.  You can then conditionally check that before calling close.

Comment: which state should I lift up?

Answer (score 0):

You should validate in the parent component and pass the result of the logic to the child Modal, then use prop drilling to pass the value of showModal to the modal and evaluate it to open or close it